# in magento 2.4.6 cloud project, at frontend website got styles-m.css not found. frontend website is broken. But backend dashboard works well

Tags: magento2

I have one magento2 cloud project. magento 2.4.6 version. Disable merge and mini css in app/etc/config.php. after push to staging and redeploy success, the styles-m.css not found
[styles-m.css not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE7Ld.png)

.magento.app.yaml

```
# This file describes an application. You can have multiple applications
# in the same project.


# The name of this app. Must be unique within a project.
name: mymagento

# The toolstack used to build the application.
type: php:8.2
build:
    flavor: none
dependencies:
    php:
        composer/composer: '2.2.21'

# Enable extensions required by Magento 2
runtime:
    extensions:
        - redis
        - xsl
        - blackfire
        - newrelic
        - sodium

# The relationships of the application with services or other applications.
# The left-hand side is the name of the relationship as it will be exposed
# to the application in the environment variable. The right-hand
# side is in the form `<service name>:<endpoint name>`.
relationships:
    database: "mysql:mysql"
    redis: "redis:redis"
    opensearch: "opensearch:opensearch"

# The configuration of app when it is exposed to the web.
web:
    locations:
        "/": &root
            # The public directory of the app, relative to its root.
            root: "pub"
            # The front-controller script to send non-static requests to.
            passthru: "/index.php"
            index:
                - index.php
            expires: -1
            scripts: true
            allow: false
            rules:
                \.(css|js|map|hbs|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff|wbmp|ico|jng|bmp|svgz|midi?|mp?ga|mp2|mp3|m4a|ra|weba|3gpp?|mp4|mpe?g|mpe|ogv|mov|webm|flv|mng|asx|asf|wmv|avi|ogx|swf|jar|ttf|eot|woff|otf|html?)$:
                    allow: true
                ^/sitemap(.*)\.xml$:
                    passthru: "/media/sitemap$1.xml"
        "/media":
            root: "pub/media"
            allow: true
            scripts: false
            expires: 1y
            passthru: "/get.php"
        "/static": &static
            root: "pub/static"
            allow: true
            scripts: false
            expires: 1y
            passthru: "/front-static.php"
            rules:
                ^/static/version\d+/(?<resource>.*)$:
                    passthru: "/static/$resource"


# The size of the persistent disk of the application (in MB).
disk: 2048

# The mounts that will be performed when the package is deployed.
mounts:
    "var": "shared:files/var"
    "app/etc": "shared:files/etc"
    "pub/media": "shared:files/media"
    "pub/static": "shared:files/static"

hooks:
    # We run build hooks before your application has been packaged.
    build: |
        set -e
        composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:generate
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:transfer
    # We run deploy hook after your application has been deployed and started.
    deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools deploy
    # We run post deploy hook to clean and warm the cache. Available with ECE-Tools 2002.0.10.
    post_deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools post-deploy

# Default Magento 2 cron jobs
crons:
    cronrun:
        spec: "* * * * *"
        cmd: "php bin/magento cron:run"

# Environment variables
variables:
    env:
        CONFIG__DEFAULT__PAYPAL_ONBOARDING__MIDDLEMAN_DOMAIN: 'payment-broker.magento.com'
        CONFIG__STORES__DEFAULT__PAYPAL__NOTATION_CODE: 'Magento_Enterprise_Cloud'
```

.magento.env.yaml

```
stage:
  global:
    SKIP_HTML_MINIFICATION: true
  build:
      SKIP_SCD: false
      SCD_STRATEGY: "compact"
  deploy:
    CLEAN_STATIC_FILES: trueƒst
    CRON_CONSUMERS_RUNNER:
      cron_run: true
      max_messages: 1000
      consumers:
        - product_action_attribute.update
        - exportProcessor
        - async.operations.all
```

It need 40 minutes to generate static file
[generate slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33sZ9.png)

I could redeploy with git commit --allow-empty -m "redeploy", But each time got css not found.

Expected:
Success to generate styles-m.css

Comment: Did you manage to fix deployment on production with minify of js and css?

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe Commerce Cloud,
Following are steps for Troubleshooting the issue.

1. On Local setup cloud project (if possible use docker)
2. Run php setup:static-content:deploy from the Project root.
3. Check if styles are generating or not.
4. If you find that same error on local then you can visit the url in local, in general if less has any issues you will able to see error on browser link of css itself.
5. If there is not any error then check how the theme is written. some times it might happen due to the wrong theme structure or layouts.

Quick Deployment

1. For after deployment you can try to change following on .magento.env.yaml

```html
stage:
   build:
       SCD_STRATEGY: "quick"
```

2. and if you have specific theme only then you can add SCD_MATRIX AS WELL

```html
stage:    
   build:
      SCD_MATRIX:
            "Magento/backend":
                language:
                    - en_US
                    - en_GB
            "yourthemevendor/themename":
                language:
                    - en_AU
                    - en_CA
                    - en_GB
                    - en_NZ
                    - en_US
                    - sv_SE
                    - de_DE
```

Change languages as per the stores you are using, it will save deployment time with very specificics.